# oracle 10G forms connection with Oracle database 10G Enterprise Edition in windows 7

Tags: oracle-10g

I am trying to connect Oracle Forms 10g version (9.0.4) to the Oracle 10G Enterprise Edition.

At first I tried to connect to the db without setting the "Local Net Service Name Configuration" in Oracle Net Configuration Assistant.I got the error[image]

After setting the "Local Net Service Name Configuration" in Oracle Net Configuration Assistant, I am still getting an error

[image]

Can anyone explain me how to connect to the database with forms as I am stubbed as of long struggle for connecting the database?

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

The following are the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora contents

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = RahulSingh-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

The message is an indication of incompatibility of Forms version that you're using with your OS, i.e. Windows 7.

You'll need to install Oracle Forms [version 10.1.2.0.2 with patchset 3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/as-certification-r2-101202-095871.html#BABGCBHA) to have this corrected.

Else you can also install [Oracle Forms 11g R2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/overview/index-098877.html) which is certified for Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Add this to both tnsnames.ora or

hr =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = hr)
      (ORACLE_HOME = )
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

Comment: It might help future visitors if you explained why this works.